# Sorting a numeric String using `sort`

Tags: bash, csv, sorting

I read through the `sort` manual but I feel like I'm missing something.

#### Source File

Here is the CSV file I'm trying to sort:

```bsh
$ cat SAMPLE.CSV 
compid,active,tagno
-2147483646,1,"1"
-2147483645,0,"10000"
-2147483644,0,"1002"
-2147483127,1,"76245.1"
-2147483126,1,"76245.2"
-2147468087,1,"76245"
```

#### Desired Result

I'm trying to sort by the third (last) column, also known as the `tagno` column. The desired result should look like this:

```bsh
compid,active,tagno
-2147483646,1,"1"
-2147483644,0,"1002"
-2147483645,0,"10000"
-2147468087,1,"76245"
-2147483127,1,"76245.1"
-2147483126,1,"76245.2"
```

#### Vain Attempts

By all accounts, the following command should do exactly what I want:

```bsh
$ sort SAMPLE.CSV -n -k 3 -t ','
-2147468087,1,"76245"
-2147483126,1,"76245.2"
-2147483127,1,"76245.1"
-2147483644,0,"1002"
-2147483645,0,"10000"
-2147483646,1,"1"
compid,active,tagno
```

I even tried with the "general-numeric-sort" option:

```bsh
$ sort SAMPLE.CSV -g -k 3 -t ','
-2147468087,1,"76245"
-2147483126,1,"76245.2"
-2147483127,1,"76245.1"
-2147483644,0,"1002"
-2147483645,0,"10000"
-2147483646,1,"1"
compid,active,tagno
```

This the first time using `sort` so I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

#### `sort` version

```bsh
$ sort --version
2.3-Apple (99)
```

Help please?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471101/sort-csv-file-by-column-priority-using-the-sort-command  and see comments on the accepted answer there too.

Comment: @barlop Thanks for the pointer but I've combed through that and still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default field separator in `sort` is non-blank to blank transition. You need a different separator here: a doublequote.

```
sort -t'"' -k2n SAMPLE.CSV
```

You are then sorting by the 2nd column. Fortunately, the second column is empty in the header line, so it comes first.

Comment: First of all, you're a genius. Secondly, wat? I thought I would have to specify a comma as the field separator, like `-t ','`?

Comment: A number must start with a digit (or - or .), not doublequote, so comma doesn't help here.

Comment: Gotcha. I have a follow-up question. Your command is sorting numbers with a letter in it oddly, like so: `-2147466194,1,"1361B.2"\n
-2147466195,1,"1361B.1"\n
-2147466196,1,"1361B"` Any idea how to fix those? (for clarity, I'll toss this in the original question as an edit)

Comment: Please, don't. To ask a new question, create a new question.

Comment: You're right. I created another question and answered it myself over here: https://superuser.com/questions/1307618/sorting-a-csv-file-by-a-column-with-alphanumeric-values/1307619#1307619  Thanks again for your help!